# Highest values in vector< vector<Point3f> >

Tags: c++, opencv, c++11, vector

I know the how to find the highest values for the data types like `int`, `float`, `double`, etc. But here I am working with `x`, `y`, & `z` coordinates by using `Point3f`. So can anybody help to find the highest values of `x`, `y` or `z` from  a `std::vector` of `std::vector`?

```
std::vector< std::vector<Point3f> > cluster_points;
```

for simplicity lets say I want to find the highest values only for `x` axis among all.

Comment: You could convert the `vector<Point3f>` to a Mat and use [this](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=minmaxloc#minmaxloc) to find min and max.

Comment: @RickM Thanks for suggestion. I thought about this before but as I am using Point3f in other references, I don't want to convert it into Mat. If I do so, I have to reverse it whenever I need. And that will make it bit slow.

Comment: It wouldn't make it slow if you do it like [this](http://www.swarthmore.edu/NatSci/mzucker1/opencv-2.4.10-docs/doc/user_guide/ug_mat.html#memory-management-and-reference-counting). It is just a pointer to the data.

Comment: @RickM Okay, I'll have a look at the documentation, and will try it. Thanks for suggestions

Comment: Do whatever you do for a `vector<vector<double> >` but provide a custom comparator, which compares just the x-coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know opencv, so can be simpler solutions but...

What about a couple of `std::for_each()` with a couple of lambda functions?

```
std::vector<std::vector<Point3f>> vvp { /* some data */ };

auto mx = vvp[0][0].x;
auto my = vvp[0][0].y;
auto mz = vvp[0][0].z;

std::for_each(vvp.cbegin(), vvp.cend(),
   [&](std::vector<Point3f> const & vp)
       { std::for_each(vp.cbegin(), vp.cend(),
            [&](Point3f const & p)
               { mx = std::max(mx, p.x);
                 my = std::max(my, p.y);
                 mz = std::max(mz, p.z); }); });
```

If you can use C++14, so lambda functions with `auto` arguments, the double `std::for_each()` part can be simply written as

```
std::for_each(vvp.cbegin(), vvp.cend(), [&](auto const & vp)
 { std::for_each(vp.cbegin(), vp.cend(), [&](auto const & p)
    { mx = std::max(mx, p.x);
      my = std::max(my, p.y);
      mz = std::max(mz, p.z); }); });
```

so without expliciting `Poinf3f` and usable by other point-3d like types.

Comment: ahhh, C++11 you beauty, ** tears **.

Comment: @RickM. - and C++14 is even better (answer modified)

Comment: Just one word - **EPIC**

Answer (score 1):

This is C++14.

This is a solution without explicit loops in client code.

```
template<class F>
auto foreacher(F&& f) {
  return [f=std::forward<F>(f)](auto&& r)mutable{
    for (auto&& e:decltype(r)(r))
      f(decltype(e)(e));
  };
}

std::vector<std::vector<Point3f>> data = {whatever};
auto mx = data[0][0].x;
auto task = foreacher(foreacher([&](Point3f const& e){
  mx = (std::max)(mx, e.x);
}));

task(data);
```

We take our lambda that solves the problem on an element, then we wrap it in two modifiers that make it iterate over the contents of the argument.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6bf81ce906ce3574).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::accumulate` which maps to this task pretty well:

```
const auto min = std::numeric_limits<float>::min();
Point3f init( min, min, min );
std::vector< std::vector<Point3f> > cluster_points;
auto max = std::accumulate( cluster_points.begin(), cluster_points.end(), init, []( const Point3f &p, const std::vector<Point3f> &v ) {
    return std::accumulate( v.begin(), v.end(), p, []( const Point3f &p1, const Point3f &p2 ) {
       return Point3f( std::max( p1.x, p2.x ), std::max( p1.y, p2.y ), std::max( p1.z, p2.z ) );
   }
} ) );
```

And this requires only C++11, with C++14 it could be simplified by using `auto` arguments in lambdas

Answer (score 1):

Although there are several great answers, I am just writing the one which is *pure opencv*, I leave the investigation upon the fastest way to you.

```
std::vector<Point3f> points;
// .. fill the array
Mat pointsMat = Mat(points).reshape(1);
```

[**Quoting**](http://www.swarthmore.edu/NatSci/mzucker1/opencv-2.4.10-docs/doc/user_guide/ug_mat.html#memory-management-and-reference-counting) - 
As a result we get a 32FC1 matrix with 3 columns instead of 32FC3 matrix with 1 column. pointsMat uses data from points and will not deallocate the memory when destroyed. In this particular instance, however, developer has to make sure that lifetime of points is longer than of pointsMat.

Then, now that you have a Mat with all your `Point3f`, you could use the following:

```
minMaxLoc(pointsMat, &minVal, &maxVal);
```

If you wish to do this for `std::vector<std::vector<Point3f>> All_points` you can make a single channel `Mat` with number of columns = `All_points.size() * 3` and use the same function `minMaxLoc`. This will give you `minVal` and `maxVal` along all point sets.

You can also get the location of the `minVal` and `maxVal` like:

```
minMaxLoc(pointsMat, &minVal, &maxVal, &minLoc, &maxLoc);
```

which is of course in the *reshaped Mat*.

Hope it helps!

*P.S. Kudos to the C++11 and C++14 answers*