# Find maximum for Point3f in vector of vector

Tags: c++, opencv, c++11, vector

I saw a bit similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43896491/highest-values-in-vector-vectorpoint3f?noredirect=1#comment74828274_43896491) but I didn't get what I am looking  for. I have something like this

`vector< vector<Point3f> > 3dpoints;`

Now lets say I want to find the maximum only for x coordinates and want to print all other values associate to it. I tried like below but it is throwing some error *request for member 'begin' ...*

```
for( auto r = 0; r < 3dpoints.size(); r++ ) {
    for( auto s = 0; s < 3dpoints[r].size(); s++ ) {
        cout<< max_element( 3dpoints[r][s].x.begin(), 3dpoints[r][s].x.end() ) << endl; 
    } 
}
```

I know I am missing something basic but can't get it. Can anyone help me to find max in Point3f?

Comment: tried like what below? whats in that thread? can you post what you tried?

Comment: can you also add the error message to your code?  and what is the data type of x?  I would think it may be a double or float so it wouldn't have a begin...  and can you show us your max_element function?

Comment: `*max_element(..)`, else you try to print the iterator.

Comment: @Jarod42 I tried that, but didn't work as well

Comment: @Eddge Yes, data type of x is float

Comment: and you have to provide special compare function to check only `x` field.

Comment: `*max_element( 3dpoints[r][s].begin(), 3dpoints[r][s].end(), LessByX{} );` With appropriate `LessByX` Functor.

Comment: @Eddge I added error message, it;s like "request for member 'begin' ...", and max_element is inbuilt function

Comment: @Jarod42 Okay, thank's for the response. I don't know much about Functor. So may be that is the problem. I'll try to find some related information.

Comment: Can you explain "print all other values associate to it" in more detail? Do you want to print all points with this X value or only first one? Do you want to do that for each subvector or all of them?

Comment: @Slava Okay. So Point3f (3f means 3d points with float data types) stores 3 coordinates (x,y,z). So now I want all those x, y & z values only when x is at the highest point.

Comment: @noexistence for each subvector individually or all of them?

Comment: @Slava For each sub vector individually

Comment: What compiler are you using? `3dpoints` [should not be accepted as a valid identifier](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.name).

Comment: @StoryTeller I am using g++ 5.4.0

Comment: Are you sure this is your code? [I can't get this identifier to compile, even with extensions enabled](https://wandbox.org/permlink/0a3CA5Zna7VVWgGr).

Comment: @StoryTeller It's not the whole code, it's just a code snippet. The whole code consists more than 1300 lines. And what Slava has posted in 2nd answer, worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template<class F>
struct projected_order_t {
  F f;
  template<class Lhs, class Rhs>
  bool operator()(Lhs const& lhs, Rhs const& rhs)const {
    return f(lhs) < f(rhs);
  }
};
template<class F>
projected_order_t<F> projected_order(F f) {
  return {std::move(f)};
}

auto max_elem_of_vector = [](std::vector<Point3f> const& pts){
  return std::max_element( pts.begin(), pts.end(), projected_order(
    [](Point3f pt){ return pt.x; }
  ));
};
auto max_x_of_vector = [](std::vector<Point3f> const& pts){
  auto it = max_elem_of_vector(pts);
  if (it == pts.end()) return std::numeric_limits<float>::min();
  return it->x;
};
auto max_elem_of_v_of_v = [](std::vector<std::vector<Point3f>> const& pts){
  auto it = std::max_element( pts.begin(), pts.end(), projected_order(
    max_x_of_vector
  ));
  auto minf = std::numeric_limits<float>::min();
  auto minp = Point3f{minf, minf, minf};
  if (it == pts.end())
    return minp
  auto it2 = max_elem_of_vector(*it);
  if (it2 == it->end()) 
    return minp;
  return *it2;
};
```

`max_elem_of_v_of_v` should solve your problem.

Projected order takes a projection (a mapping from type A to type B), and returns an ordering on type A that uses the mapping to B and `<` on `B`.

The first use maps a point to its `x` coordinate; this lets us find the max element in a vector of points by the `x` coordinate.

The second use maps a vector of points to the max x of any element in that vector.  We use that to find the vector with the largest x element.

We then extract the element from that maximal vector with the largest x element.

It returns min float values if there is no min element.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with single pass:

```
vector< vector<Point3f> > points;
vector<Point3f> maxes;
for( const auto &v : points ) {
    for( const auto &p : v ) {
        if( not maxes.empty() and maxes.front().x < p.x )
            maxes.clear();
        if( maxes.empty() or maxes.front().x == p.x )
            maxes.push_back( p );
    }
}
// here you have list of all points with max x in maxes
```

This is an example to show the idea, in your code you probably want to replace < and == with function using epsilon to properly compare floating numbers.

PS code shown do that for all data, you mention that you need to do that for each row individually. Code can be easily changed to do that:

```
for( const auto &v : points ) {
    vector<Point3f> maxes;
    for( const auto &p : v ) {
        if( not maxes.empty() and maxes.front().x < p.x )
            maxes.clear();
        if( maxes.empty() or maxes.front().x == p.x )
            maxes.push_back( p );
    }
    // print maxes here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your latest comments the code should be:

```
for( auto r = 0; r < 3dpoints.size(); r++ ) {
   auto highest = max_element(begin(3dpoints[r]), end(3dpoints[r]),
                              [](const Point3f &lhs, const Point3f &rhs) 
                                { return lhs.x < rhs.x; })
   cout << highest->y << highest->z << endl;
}
```

What you are doing wrong:

- 3dpoints[r][s].x is a float, does not have begin()/end().
- you need to provide a custom compare function for max_element.

**EDIT**
Thanks @Slava for pointing out that std::max_element returns an iterator.

Comment: I tried your code, but says `class __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<cv::Point3_<float>*, std::vector<cv::Point3_<float> > >’ has no member named ‘y’ ` and same for `z`

Comment: @noexistence  I do not know the content of Point3f, replace 'y', 'z' with the members that represent the y and z values.
`highest` is the Point3f with the greatest x value from a subvector `3dpoints[r]`

Comment: Memebers are 'x' 'y' and 'z' indeed but `std::max_element` returns iterator. So your code needs to be changed to `highest->x` etc

Comment: @Slava thanks, sorry for the mistake, I wrote it directly and didn't check the return type. Updating right now.